# Sorting a list of objects with OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `object (KS)`, which holds `ID and Title` (which has a number as part of the Title).

All I'm trying to do is sort it into descending order. The object has:

```
ID    Title
1     1 Outlook VPN 
2     2 Outlook Access
3     4 Access VBA
4     3 Excel Automation
```

So when order by Title, it should read:

```
ID    Title
3     4 Access VBA
4     3 Excel Automation
2     2 Outlook Access
1     1 Outlook VPN
```

The code I'm using to sort it is:

```
IEnumerable<KS> query = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title);
```

However, **query** still has the objects in the original order!

Is there something to do with having numbers at the start of **Title** that I'm missing?

**EDIT**

I've added the code from the controller for clarity:

```
    [HttpPost]
    // [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    // id is a string of words eg: "outlook access vpn"
    // I split the words and want to check the Title to see how many words appear
    // Then sort by the most words found
    public JsonResult Lookup(string id)
    {
        List<string> listOfSearch = id.Split(' ').ToList();
        var results = db.KS.Where(x => listOfSearch.Any(item => x.Title.Contains(item)));

        // search each result, and count how many of the search words in id are found
        // then add the count to the start of Title
            foreach (KS result in results)
            {
                result.KSId = 0;
                foreach (string li in listOfSearch)
                {
                    if (result.Title.ToLower().Contains(li.ToLower()))
                    {
                        result.KSId += 1;
                    }
                }
                result.Title = result.KSId.ToString() + " " + result.Title;
            }
       // sort the results based on the Title - which has number of words at the start
       IEnumerable<KS> query = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title).ToList();
       return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is a screenshot **after** query has been populated showing Titles in the order: 1, 2, 1, 1:

[image: VSSS]

Model for the object if it helps is:

```
 public class KS
{
    public int KSId { get; set; }
    public string KSSol { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Fix { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `query` rather than `results`? You haven't shown what you're doing with `query` after initializing the variable.

Comment: How are you accesing query?

Comment: We need more code. Show us how you use `query`, at the very least.

Comment: Hi - I've added all of the controller code above - this is a simple FAQ type system - all I want to do is pass a string of words, count how many of those are found in Title - add the count to the start of Title and then sort and return the data - thanks.

Comment: Were you using ToList() before?

Comment: No, I wasn't - but adding it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Check Jamiec answer, that new code is different from the first one you gave us. There's your problem

Comment: Hi - KSId and Title should contain the same number to start with - I've changed my code back to Title anyway, and posted a screenshot above.

Comment: It might be more useful to put a `.ToList()` in the declaration of your `results` local variable, i.e. after the `.Where(...)`. Is the type of `KS` a struct?

Comment: Hi - Ks is just a model - this is an FAQ type system - there is a solution reference, KSSol, a Title, and a Fix (which contains the steps to answer the FAQ) - thanks, Mark

Comment: I don't know how your Json object is handling the `Enumerable`. Could you try to iterate it with a simple `foreach` loop, right before the `return` statements, and see if they show up in the right order?

Comment: Hi - the screenshot I've added shows what query looks like before the 'return' statement is executed - still in the wrong order though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, put a `.ToList()` where you declare your `results` variable. That is:

```
var results = db.KS.Where(x => listOfSearch.Any(item => x.Title.Contains(item)))
    .ToList();
```

If you don't do that, the `foreach` loop will modify objects that might not be the same as the objects you sort later, because the database query is run again each time you enumerate your `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: This makes no difference as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jamiec Sure, see added sentence in my answer above.

Comment: Yup, totally right. I missed the fact it was a Database call!

Comment: Thank you - that sorted it for me.  And thank you to everyone else too.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but maybe this will help someone using C#. I used the following expressions to sort a list of objects based on their quantity parameter in ascending or descending order. Can modify it to compare text as the original question was concerned with.

Ascending Order:

```
locationMaterials.Sort((x, y) => x.Quantity.CompareTo(y.Quantity));
```

Descending Order:

```
locationMaterials.Sort((x, y) => y.Quantity.CompareTo(x.Quantity));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just ignore the strange behavior and go the safe way:

```
List<KS> query = results.ToList();
query.Sort((a, b) => a.Whatever.CompareTo(b.Whatever));

return Json(query, blah);
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple did this and it worked for me :-

```
var sortedOrder = Query.OrderBy(b => b.Title.Substring(b.Title.IndexOf(" ")));
```

All I have done is SubString the Title at the index of of the blank space when ordering the objects in the sequence, that way, the OrderBy is looking at the first character in the title rather than the number at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `.ToList()`

```
IEnumerable<KS> query = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

`results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title)` is a query, and it has no data. 
`ToList()` forces the query to be executed.

**[EDIT]**

My answer assumes that your `results` has acually *not* been materialized, and that *that* is the source of your problem.

Comment: That's because OrderByDescending only stores info about how to order, it doesnt really order until the results are enumerated.

Comment: But `query` should already have the results in the right order... the OP claims it doesn't.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso: Well if you iterate over `query`, you should get the right results. You *don't* need to call `ToList()`. It's evaluated lazily, but that's a different matter.

Comment: When you access query you should get results ordered... you don't need to call ToList

Comment: Agree with the above. The missing `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` is a common mistake, but it has nothing to do with this case. We need more code to understand the source of the problem.

Comment: i believe hes talking about query object itself and not an enumeration of it so it's normal that they arent ordered yet.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Why would he care about the collection that `query` encapsulates? When iterating over it, it should be in descending order as expected. Also note that you can edit a comment within 5 minutes since posting it to avoid spamming.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso he got wrong results, to get the results he had to enumarate the query before...

Comment: Where are you seeing enumeration? I dont see any enumeration or iteration or even access to query. How can you tell so certain that he's doing that properly?

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso in debug mode the query need to be evaluated or enumerated to see the results... in fact you have to click the refresh button to get the items in the object inspector